# Assembly has 2 assembly rows build error, when using dotfuscator

Tags: c#, build, dotfuscator

I'm running the free version of Dotfuscator bundled with VS2008 on my console app, but keep getting the following error.

This assembly has 2 assembly rows.
Build Error.

Any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: You can also try asking on the dotfuscator support forum: http://www.preemptive.com/forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a problem with the 3rd party licensing software